# I got "Some sites could not be found"

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

After I clicked "Help > Check for updates" and I got a popup saying "No updates were found" then another popup saying:

"Some sites could not be found. See the error log for more details:
  No repository found at file:/C:/ blah blah
  No repository found at file:/C:/ blah blah
  No repository found at file:/C:/ blah blah"

I just want to know where they are so I can change them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites